# MS Project - Duration without a start and finish date

Tags: ms-project

I'm currently working on a schedule where we have several options. Due to the fact there are several of them, and it's not decided which we are going to be asked to perform, I want to be able to show the durations only to the client and not the actual start and finish, is this possible? See below for an example. Our planner says this isn't possible, but I can't see why we can't just leave the date fields empty.

[image: Table with duration of each event, without start and end]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is entirely possible and the easiest way to use it is using a View.

First go to the Task Sheet view, then simply "hide" the columns you don't want to appear in the view (right click on the column heading and select Hide)

When you are happy with the report save the View using a name meaningful to you.

Simply run and distribute copies of that view and you will have all the information you need and none of the start/finish dates or other columns you don't wish to appear.

EDIT: Another solution you may wish to examine would be to continue using the Gantt Chart, but use relative period numbering for the timescale labels (i.e. Month 1, Week 2 etc.) As long as you hide the explicit Date columns you will be able to show all options on the Gantt next to each other within implying "real" dates. To do this just double-click on the timescale at the top of the chart and edit the "Timescale" drop down for each of the Tiers to achieve whatever effect you want.

Comment: Hi Marv, thanks for replying. Im assuming that hides all the columns though and not just on the options?

Comment: Well it hides all the columns in the *View*, it doesn't remove the data (I'm not sure that is even possible)... If you used the View to report on only the Option(s) it would only show what you want. In other words your Gantt chart contains all the data required by MSP for planning and scheduling but you use the Report to distribute the Option plans rather than the underlying data...

Comment: See also my edit to my answer for an alternative...

Answer (score 0):

[Share a schedule without revealing actual dates](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/project/2012/01/03/share-a-schedule-without-revealing-actual-dates/) may be useful. This way you may set a duration without specific dates and then hide the columns for start and end

Comment: Please add some explanation. Link-only answers typically get flagged by the community.

Comment: Ok, thanks for remarks

Comment: Hi K. Tsvekov. As it is, your answer requires the link to have any value. If by any chance the link gets broken, the answer isn't valuable. Consider sharing here the most relevant parts as well.